# Is there a setting/config to increase send volume on PMTA?

Tags: email, smtp, setting, pmta

I would like to increase my send rate on PMTA. I am not encountering any errors or something, I just want to test my server's full capacity.

Comment: Afaik your question is more like a sysadmin question as programming. And it is also too broad, you didn't even share the name of your MTA.

Comment: I am using PowerMTA and I just wanna know if there is a setting/config to increase my send volume.